# Sentencias sql con mayusculas

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Mi base esta en un servidor
Tengo sentecias sql ejemplo:

`SELECT *  FROM Usuario`

pero no hace la sentencia, pero si pongo el nombre de la tabla en minuscula si se realiza, porque?
hay forma de hacer que las haga aun en mayuscula?

Answer (score 3):

De manera general:

De acuerdo a la documentación de la [sensibilidad a mayúsculas y minúsculas de los identificadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), en mySQL:

> Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case-sensitive in Windows, but are case-sensitive in most varieties of Unix

En resumen, los nombres de tablas y de triggers son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas, según el sistema operativo del servidor. En Windows suelen ser no sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas mientras si lo son en la mayoría de variedades de Unix (incluyendo Linux).

Además, existe la variable de sistema [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names), que afecta cómo el servidor maneja la sensibilidad a mayúsculas y minúsculas en los nombres de tablas.

Ahora, sobre tu pregunta específica, estoy asumiendo que tu servidor está sobre un sistema *nix, de otra forma el *select* funcionaría sin importar cómo escribes el nombre de la tabla.

Si quieres que la sentencia funcione con el nombre de la tabla en mayúscula, debes asegurarte de conocer el valor de la variable `lower_case_table_names` y, según esta, seguir las recomendaciones siguientes:

| Valor | Significado | Recomendación |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | case sensitive | Debes crear la tabla con el nombre según lo quieres y utilizarlo siempre de la misma forma, por ejemplo: `create table Usuario (id int not null, nombre varchar(100) not null)` y `select * from Usuario` debieran funcionar bien |
| 1 | case insensitive | No importa como crees la tabla y como la consultes, las tablas siempre son creadas en minúsculas y las comparaciones no son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas |
| 2 | case insensitive/2 | Las tablas son creadas según das el nombre al momento de la creación, pero las comparaciones se hacen en minúsculas |

De esto, diría que probablemente tu sistema está configurado con la variable `lower_case_table_names` en 0, pero creaste la tabla con el nombre en minúscula (o el valor de dicha variable cambió luego de crear la tabla).

Si ese es el caso, para resolverlo, puedes crear una nueva tabla con el nombre en minúsculas y la misma estructura.

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos.**

Verifica lo que ocurre; en lo particular me he topado con eso en los siguientes casos:

***Caso 1***

Verifica el servidor; si tus entorno de desarrollo y donde te falla son Linux o alguna distro similar; al momento de crear la tabla se genero de distinta forma (forzada a minúscula).

***Caso 2***

Si tu entorno de desarrollo es Windows y donde te falla es Linux (alguna distro); en Windows no importa pero en Linux sí afecta estén en mayúsculas/minúsculas.

Son los dos casos básicos que con frecuencia me he topado.

Saludos espero te sirva u oriente.

Comment: Sin conocer el entorno del OP, ni la configuración de su servidor, ni la versión ni tipo ni motor de SQL que está usando el OP; tu publicación podría ser mas un comentario que una respuesta. En todo caso, SQL no es case sensitive por defecto, esto depende más del COLLATE al momento de crear la base de datos o incluso de instalar el propio DBMS

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu creas las tablas en algún gestor de bases de datos, por ejemplo mariadb, phpmyadmin o pgadmin que son los que he usado; no importa como escribas el nombre de las tablas porque cuando se ejecute la sentencia sql de la creación de las mismas, tomará el nombre en minúscula. Por tanto, las consultas a las BD deben tener el mismo nombre que como están registradas(quiere decir, minúsculas).
Ese es un por qué no te funciona de esa manera que estas haciéndolo

Comment: pero lo que pasa es que las sentencia con la mayuscula si funciona en el localhost y ya en el servidor no